# Qemu AARCH64 of Raspi3 and smp 4, all cores are suspended except core/thread 0

Tags: multithreading, raspberry-pi, qemu, arm64, bare-metal

I am trying to enable multicore features on qemu of raspi3 which I did similar thing on Qemu.riscv. But when I run the qemu command, all other cores seem suspended except core 0 show as followings:

The command I am using is

```
qemu:
    qemu-system-aarch64 \
        -M raspi3b  \
        -m 1024M    \
        -smp 4 \
        -S -s \
        -kernel kernel8.img \
        -serial stdio
```

Initial code I have is like this

```
_start:
    //single core: only hart 0 jump to kernel
    mrs x0, mpidr_el1
    and x0, x0, #0b11
 
    cbz x0, _core_0
 
    //cbz x0, 1f
other_cores:
    wfe
    b other_cores
 
 
_core_0:
    mrs x0, CurrentEL
    and x0, x0, #0b1100
    cmp x0, #0b1000
    ......
```

(gdb) info threads

Id   Target Id                    Frame

- 1    Thread 1.1 (CPU#0 [running]) main () at main.c:44

  2    Thread 1.2 (CPU#1 [running]) 0x000000000000030c in ?? ()

  3    Thread 1.3 (CPU#2 [running]) 0x000000000000030c in ?? ()

  4    Thread 1.4 (CPU#3 [running]) 0x000000000000030c in ?? ()

qemu-system-aarch64 -version

> QEMU emulator version 6.2.0

Copyright (c) 2003-2021 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers

Could you give me some guidance how to enable multicore on qemu?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It has been solved

Answer (score 0):

Multicore is enabled, but since you have passed your guest image as '-kernel' QEMU is booting it in the way the Linux kernel wants to be booted, which is to say that only a single core is started running the guest image code, and the other three sit in a spinloop in a bit of boot code that QEMU provides, waiting for the kernel to poke the known addresses in RAM with the addresses for the secondary cores to jump to.

You need to either (a) look up the Linux kernel boot protocol for raspberry pi, and have your guest code do the right thing to make the secondary cores leave the spinloop, or (b) use one of the other ways to get QEMU to load guest code (eg the generic loader or the -bios option), in which case QEMU will just start all four cores running your code.

Generally speaking, SMP boot protocol for different architectures can be pretty significantly different, and sometimes it differs across machine types too, so you should check documentation for the hardware you're emulating.

(Consider also whether 'raspi3' is really the board type you want to use.)